# TextInput losing focus

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Basically, I have a form that contains a list of fields that also includes `TextInput`s.

The issue I'm having is that each time the user focuses the `TextInput`, it immediately loses focus, and also when I set state as the user types. Also, there's a slight delay before it loses focus as the user types, as opposed to it losing focus immediately when the user brings it into focus for the first time.

I don't face this issue when debugging on my own device, I only experience it when debugging with other devices.

This is just a simplified version of the actual code:

```js
const data = [
  {
    options: [],
    type: "text",
    required: true,
    label: "first name"
  },
  {
    options: [],
    type: "text",
    required: true,
    label: "last name"
  }
];

function App() {
  const [names, setNames] = React.useState({});

  return (
    <FlatList
      data={data}
      keyExtractor={({ label }) => label}
      renderItem={({ item }) => {
        const { type, label, options, required } = item;

        return (
          <TextInput
            placeholder={label}
            value={names[label]}
            onChangeText={value => {
              setNames({...names, [label]: value});
            }}
          />
        );
      }}
    />
  );
}
```

I'm not sure if it's an issue with the device or a react-native issue, or an issue with my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix the issue, I'm not sure why, but the behavior mentioned above only happens to `TextInput` elements that are at or close to the bottom of the list.

I think it has something to do with the way elements behave when the keyboard pops up. And maybe the way `FlatList` renders items. The problem stopped after I changed it to a `ScrollView` and just mapping over the data.